# When executing a query to import data from Exact Online with Invantive Control for Excel I get the error "itgenxml004"

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

When I try to execute a query within Invantive Control for Excel, I get the following error:

> **itgenxml004**
>
> U heeft geen toegang tot Administratie '873160'.  Toegang zou de restrictie erop van 100 overschrijden.  Deze kunstmatige beperking
> geldt alleen voor de huidige releases en kan opgeheven worden in de
> toekomst.  Gelieve de toegang te beperken of neem contact op met
> Invantive om deze beperking te laten opheffen.
>
> **itgenxml004**
>
> You have no access to division '873160'.  Access would exceed the restriction of 100.  This artificial restriction
> is only valid for the current releases and can be lifted in the future.  Please restrict access or contact
> Invantive to get this restriction remedied.

What could cause this error and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Exact Online, the number of divisions accessible is limited since the app provider must pay a fee to Exact Online for every division touched through an API in a month per client ID.

For Invantive Control for Excel, Invantive Composition for Word, Invantive Data Hub and Invantive Data Access Point this is limited to 100 divisions per session.

For Invantive Query Tool and [Online SQL Editor](https://online-sql-editor.com), this is limited to 3 divisions per session.

This is similar how for instance Amazon Web Services restricts by default the number of allocatable Elastic IP addresses to 10.

When you get this error:

Either restrict the number of divisions access, using a statement such as

```
use a,b,c
```

to restrict the SQL only being executed on the divisions (partitions) a, b and c.

Or when you really need to access more than 100 Exact Online divisions in a SQL statement, you need to contact your Invantive contact person and indicate what the maximum number of divisions should be in the range 100..5000. Also, you will need to include your data container ID which is something like:

https://start.exactonline.nl/1231232

You can find it labeled 'site ID' in the Help menu and then Diagnostics on the first tab. Or find it using:

```
select value
from   exactonlinerest..systemdatacontainerproperties 
where  name='data-container-id'
and    data_container_alias='default'
```